# Pandas ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous, when indexing dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am trying to apply Boolean indexing on my dataframe `outlier_locations` with the following code:

```
outlier_locations = month[(month.pickup_longitude != 0 and month.pickup_latitude != 0) & ((month.pickup_longitude <= -74.15) or (month.pickup_latitude <= 40.5774)or \
                   (month.pickup_longitude >= -73.7004) or (month.pickup_latitude>= 40.9176))]
```

However, I get the error (full traceback below):

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Boolean indexing with Pandas series, you need to use **bitwise** `&` / `|` operators for "and" / "or" conditions respectively. For readability, you can also split your mask into components:

```
m1 = month[['pickup_longitude', 'pickup_latitude']].ne(0).all(1)
m2 = month['pickup_longitude'].le(-74.15)
m3 = month['pickup_latitude'].le(40.5774)
m4 = month['pickup_longitude'].ge(-73.7004)
m5 = month['pickup_latitude'].ge(40.9176)

outlier_locations = month[m1 & (m2 | m3 | m4 | m5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `and` and `or` to `&` and `|` respectively.